# C++ any iterator with a specific value type?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Suppose I have a function template to loop through any iterator of some container:

```
template<class iter_type>
void f(iter_type start, iter_type finish)
{
   // loop from start to finish
}
```

Now the thing is I know the `value_type` of that container (and `f()` only makes sense with that particular `value_type`).  Is there a way to restrict `iter_type` to have a particular `value_type`?

I can probably inherit from `std::iterator`, but `f()` is just really a small piece of code that doesn't deserve a dedicated class.

Comment: If you know the container type, maybe you can specialize on that and refer to its `::iterator` type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the `value_type` of the iterator via [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), and then check it at the compile time, e.g.

```
template<class iter_type>
void f(iter_type start, iter_type finish)
{
    static_assert(
      std::is_same<
        typename std::iterator_traits<iter_type>::value_type,
        specific_value_type>::value, 
      "The value_type must be specific_value_type.");

    // loop from start to finish
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/OTGP22333)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template<class iter_type>
auto f(iter_type start, iter_type finish)
 -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
                            typename std::iterator_traits<iter_type>::value_type,
                            particular_value_type
                                        >::value, void>::type
{
   // loop from start to finish
}
```

This will make the restriction part of your function's signature, which means you can have another function template of the same name and arguments, as long as it is disabled for this particular `value_type`.

**Edit**: Using iterator_traits to make this more robust.

Comment: What would happen if I give it a iterator with value_types other than particular_value_type?  Does it generate a function that does nothing, or there'll be compile time error?

Comment: It will generate an compile time error. `enable_if` defines a type `type` that is equal to its second template argument (`void` in this case) only if its first template argument is `true`. As we're using `type` as return type of the function, it will be ill defined if `type` is not defined.

Comment: @MetroWind This means however that the generated error is not particular helpful, so if you want the restriction only to warn you when you're doing something wrong, you should probaly go with songyuanyao's solution.

Comment: yes, I was thinking of the same thing.  Given the usual confusing-ness of c++ type errors (to me anyway), custom error message sounds very attractive.